# Как сделать вывод объемного текста в Андроид приложении (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Пишу приложение по типу книги-туториал, как вывести объемный текст что бы и отформатировать можно было (выделить некоторые слова например, идт) и вообще с ним работать, а не просто вывести. Не в "стринг" же его засовывать ? Спасибо ...

Comment: Посмотрите `SpannableString`

Comment: @Jarvis_J - спасибо, сейчас попробую ...

Comment: @Northwood_FX под объемным текстом понимается текст, который может быть частично красным, частично жирным черным, частично курсив?

Comment: @Maxgmer, делаю туториал по Dart, перевожу на русский доку, хочу сделать мобильное приложение (туториал), там много текста с исходниками и примерами и не понимаю как это можно правильно "загнать" во Флаттер что бы было красиво и эстетично ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, вам подойдет виджет `RichText`. Он позволяет более гибко кастомизировать текст в приложении. Вот пример:

```
  RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        //тут указывается общий стиль. Позже, указывая стили для TextSpan ниже,
        //мы переопределяем атрибуты общего стиля. Полезно, если много общего для текста.
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          children: <TextSpan> [
            TextSpan(text: "Зеленая часть текста. ", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green)), //тут переопределяем общий цвет
            TextSpan(text: "А тут курсив", style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))
          ]
      )
  );
```

`TextSpan` - кусочки текста, они потом собираются в один текст.

А если вам надо не кастомизировать, а хранить текст уже в каком-то красивом виде где-нибудь на сервере, прежде чем использовать в приложении, то тут и обычная строка подойдет. Нужно сделать свою разметку, например, жирный текст будет оборачиваться в {}. И потом написать парсер этой разметки.

Можно хранить в `Json`, с массивом `TextSpan`, и атрибутами этого текста рядом. Тут уже как вам угодно:)

Comment: Большое спасибо вам, пойду разберусь с этим ...